# setting script for retrieving ftp data

Tags: ftp

I've just compiled a software. This software automatically connect the web site (via several scripts) and retrieve data. Web sites ftp service use e-mail address as a password. Username: Anonymous.

In documentation of the installation, the below scripts are given to connect ftp without any problem.

```
set host =\hostname | \awk -F. '{print $1}'
set dom =\hostname | \awk -F. '{print $2}'
if( $dom == '' ) then
alias hostname 'echo $host.mit.edu'
endif
```

How I need to modify (or should I write as it appears) these scripts to allow the related scripts to retrieve data from the ftp. I also need to know what this scripts doing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not perhaps a direct answer; but I use a .netrc file:

Script:
`cp ~/.netrc netrc.bak ; cp sqm-netrc ~/.netrc ; ftp ftp.anoth.er.uk ; cp netrc.bak ~/.netrc`

.netrc:
`machine ftp.somewebsite.com login username1.com password fgerghjvnfg
machine ftp.anoth.er.uk login gdruug password vfohfgbsluv
machine webhost.anoth.er.uk login vrfkbv password fbgvnfebuhb
macdef init
cd public_html
cd sqm
put sqm.txt`

This logs in, performs different actions depending where it's logged in, & quits; leaving the control file safely tucked out of the way afterwards. I haven't simplified this, just obfuscated it a little!